# Tensorflow CNN regression MSE higher for train than test

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

I'm feeding a CNN with pictures to predict a value in a regression settings.

```
Input: [NUM_EXAMPLES, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS] -> [NUM_EXAMPLES, YPRED]
```

This is the loss: `loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Ypreds, labels))`

The training-loop:

```
Loop { 
    for i in range(EPOCHS):
        epoch_train_loss = 0

        for k in range(NUM_BATCHES):
            _, batch_loss = sess.run([train_step, loss], feed_dict={...})
            epoch_train_loss += (batch_loss/NUM_BATCHES)

        # calculate test loss after 1 epoch and log
        epoch_test_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={...})

        # print train and test loss after 1 epoch
        print(epoch_train_loss, epoch_test_loss)
}
```

These are the logging results:

```
Epoch: 0 (8.21s), Train-Loss: 12844071, Test-Loss: 3802676
Epoch: 1 (4.94s), Train-Loss: 3691994, Test-Loss: 3562206
Epoch: 2 (4.90s), Train-Loss: 3315438, Test-Loss: 2968338
Epoch: 3 (5.00s), Train-Loss: 1841562, Test-Loss: 417192
Epoch: 4 (4.94s), Train-Loss: 164503, Test-Loss: 3531
Epoch: 5 (4.94s), Train-Loss: 97477, Test-Loss: 1843
Epoch: 6 (4.98s), Train-Loss: 96474, Test-Loss: 4676
Epoch: 7 (4.94s), Train-Loss: 89613, Test-Loss: 1080
```

- This makes no sense to me because the train loss is greater than test loss and that should never happen.
- Am I calculating the values correctly? The loss is averaged by batch size and by dividing the batch loss with `NUM_BATCHES` I should get results that are comparable.

Comment: Do multiple runs, after shuffling the data, have the same trend?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, but I'd do it a bit differently:

```py
epoch_train_losses = []
for k in range(NUM_BATCHES):
    _, batch_loss = sess.run([train_step, loss], feed_dict={...})
    epoch_train_losses.append(batch_loss)
epoch_train_loss = np.mean(epoch_train_losses)
# print `epoch_train_loss` and `epoch_train_losses` too
```

Getting the full distribution of the losses instead of a single number (the mean) can help you inspect in detail what's going on.

Here's one possible explanation: the training and test sets *aren't properly shuffled*, so that the test set effectively mimics the part of the training set (or can even *be* the part of the training set). In this case the distribution of training losses across batches will have very high variance: some losses will be comparable to the reported test loss, some losses will be much higher, pulling the mean up.

Comment: I've uploaded the model here: https://github.com/toemm/TF-CNN-regression/blob/master/BA-CNN_so.ipynb (before was the wrong one, sorry).
Currently implemented your solution and ran it in cell [13]. You can see this weird behaviour, seems like train loss and test loss are flipped. It's probably something regarding the shuffling like you mentioned or the `initialize_datasets(...)` fn. I'm lost here, thanks again for looking over this! :)

Comment: @ivan Please reduce the number of iterations and print the whole `epoch_train_losses` list

Comment: I've done that in cell [19] of the above link. Distribution seems fine, hmm.

Comment: Agree, it looks consistent. Can you further output the distribution of `trainY` and `testY`

Comment: Updated. Cells [8], [10]. These are shuffled by `train_test_split(...)` (from `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`). Also the dataset is again shuffled in `initialize_datasets(...)` via this call `dataset_train = dataset_train.apply(tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(...))` or atleast so it should be.

Comment: @ivan take a close look at the new losses: it seems the training loss is now lower, as it should be

Comment: Well, I've added this to the code `epoch_train_losses.append(batch_loss/NUM_BATCHES)` in the meantime (which I don't think is mathematically correct) because I ran out of ideas. So still not solved. This is what you are seeing, I forgot to remove that newest cell. :/